# TEXTAREA' page item of oracle apex unable to display large number of characters from file

Tags: oracle-apex, apex, oracle-apex-5.1, oracle-apex-5

Using below code to display text in 'TEXTAREA' page item of oracle apex.

```
DECLARE
  TEMP_CLOB    CLOB;
  TEMP_OS_FILE BFILE;
  FILENAME     VARCHAR2(30);
  FILE_EXIST   NUMBER;
BEGIN
  FILENAME:='Logfile.log';
  DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(TEMP_CLOB,TRUE);
  TEMP_OS_FILE := BFILENAME ('EXPDP_DIR',FILENAME);
  FILE_EXIST := DBMS_LOB.FILEEXISTS(TEMP_OS_FILE);
  IF FILE_EXIST = 1 THEN
  DBMS_LOB.FILEOPEN(TEMP_OS_FILE, DBMS_LOB.FILE_READONLY);
  DBMS_LOB.LOADFROMFILE(TEMP_CLOB,TEMP_OS_FILE, DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(TEMP_OS_FILE));
  DBMS_LOB.FILECLOSE(TEMP_OS_FILE);
  END IF;
  :P18_DISPLAY_LOGS:=(TEMP_CLOB);
END;
```

Above code is working fine but getting error if the log file size increases. Is there any solution to resolve that i can see any size of file in that textarea page item.

Comment: Text area only supports up to 32k size, not clob in the current versions of oracle APEX. There are some plugins available, just google "apex text area clob plugin".

Answer (score 0):

why use page item?
You can use PLSQL/Dynamic Content type and print the data on each line
like

```
htp.p(TEMP_CLOB) instead of :P18_DISPLAY_LOGS:=(TEMP_CLOB);
```

pls try and provide your feedback.